# Using DirectLine v3, how do you send a message to the USER?

Tags: rest, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I'm implementing a DirectLine client for connecting WhatsApp via Twilio and the BotFramework. I've been able to:

1. Create conversations
2. Listen to the conversation's websocket
3. Send activities to the bot

For the life of me I cannot figure out how I can send an activity to the DirectLine client, so it can forward it to the user. In other words, how can I get some activity to pop-up on the DL client's websocket?

On the bot side, what I'm doing is:

1. Ask the client to create a conversation in DirectLine between the bot and the user (I'm using phone numbers as recipient/from IDs)
2. Use the new conversation and its `serviceUrl` to post an activity from the bot to the user

I've tried a bunch of different auth tokens to do this, the closest I've gotten was using the conversation's DirectLine token as a bearer auth:

```
POST https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/CONVERSATION_ID/activities
{
  "type": "message",
  "text": "message",
  "from": { "id": "whatsapp:BOT_PHONE_NUMBER" },
  "recipient": { "id": "whatsapp:USER_PHONE_NUMBER" }
}
```

Which results in this activity popping up in the websocket:

```
{
  "channelId": "directline", 
  "conversation": {"id": "CONVERSATION_ID"}, 
  "from": {"id": "whatsapp:BOT_PHONE_NUMBER"}, 
  "id": "CONVERSATION_ID|0000006", 
  "recipient": {
    "id": "BOT_ID@something", 
    "name": "Bot"
  }, 
  "serviceUrl": "https://directline.botframework.com/", 
  "text": "pls", 
  "timestamp": "2019-08-26T23:14:13.3099739Z", 
  "type": "message"
}
```

Which is obviously useless because the user's phone number is missing?! Instead the "recipient" was overwritten to the bot's.

My question is: **What exactly is the canonical way to achieve this?**

I can just bypass the BF altogether, call my client and have it send a message to the user. This means, however, that the implementation for this channel is different from all others. If this is the way to go, what's the point of the websockets then?